# maven assembly zip in linux appears broken file name(non-ascii) in windows

Tags: maven

I exploit the maven assembly to zip the folder containing non-ascii filenames in CentOS(LANG=ko_KR.UTF-8).

When I open the zip file in Windows, filename is broken to strange characters.

It appears all right in the Linux.

I checked that files compressed by command line zip in linux, correctly shows the name in Windows.

I guess it is the Java zip library deployed by the plugin that produces the blunder.

Below is the part of pom.xml and assembly descriptor.

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>maven/assembly_descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>README*</include>
        <include>LICENSE*</include>
        <include>NOTICE*</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
```

Comment: 1. Which java runs maven? 2. Try opening the zip with 7zip under Windows.

Comment: The java is sun-jdk1.6.0_37 and I opened it with 7zip.

Comment: Java 7 then might solve things, as Java 6 has some known issues, due to using native libraries (for bootstrapping the system, loading jars). Try writing your own unzip using ZipInputStream and dumping file names first.

Comment: It did not work with Java7 neither.